# Scala regex get string before the first hyphen and the entire string

Tags: regex, scala

Given a string like `abab/docId/example-doc1-2019-01-01`, I want to use Regex to extract these values:

```
firstPart = example
fullString = example-doc1-2019-01-01
```

I have this:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

case class Read(theString: String) {

  val stringFormat: Regex = """.*\/docId\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$""".r

  val stringFormat(firstPart, fullString) = theString

}
```

But this separates it like this:

```
firstPart = example
fullString = doc1-2019-01-01
```

Is there a way to retain the fullString and do a regex on that to get the part before the first hyphen? I know I can do this using the String `split` method but is there a way do it using regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
val stringFormat: Regex = ".*/docId/(([A-Za-z0-9])+-[A-Za-z0-9-]+)$".r
                                    ||_ Group 2 _|               |
                                    |                            |
                                    |_________________ Group 1 __|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKBDjH/2).

Note how capturing parentheses are re-arranged. Also, you need to swap the variables in the regex match call, see demo below (`fullString` should come before `firstPart`).

See [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/37KBcV):

```
val theString = "abab/docId/example-doc1-2019-01-01"
val stringFormat = ".*/docId/(([A-Za-z0-9]+)-[A-Za-z0-9-]+)".r
val stringFormat(fullString, firstPart) = theString
println(s"firstPart: '$firstPart'\nfullString: '$fullString'")
```

Output:

```
firstPart: 'example'
fullString: 'example-doc1-2019-01-01'
```